# Is it allowed to have multiple empty parentid's?

Tags: sql, parent-child, data-modeling

So first I have a typical table that looks like this:

| SectionID | SectionName | DivisionID | DivisionName | IndustryID | IndustryName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SectorID1 | SecNam1 | DivisionID11 | DivName11 | IndustryID111 | InduNam111 |
| SectorID1 | SecNam1 | DivisionID11 | DivName11 | IndustryID112 | InduNam112 |
| SectorID1 | SecNam1 | DivisionID12 | DivName12 | IndustryID121 | InduNam121 |
| SectorID2 | SecNam2 | DivisionID21 | DivName21 | IndustryID211 | InduNam211 |
| SectorID3 | SecNam3 | DivisionID31 | DivName31 | IndustryID311 | InduNam311 |

now I want to transform it in a more dynamic hierarchy structure with parentIds which looks like this:

| ID | ParentID | Level | Type | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 1 | SectorID1 | SecNam1 |
| 2 | NULL | 1 | SectorID2 | SecNam2 |
| 3 | NULL | 2 | SectorID3 | SecNam3 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | DivisionID11 | DivName11 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | DivisionID12 | DivName12 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | DivisionID21 | DivName21 |
| 6 | 2 | 2 | DivisionID31 | DivName31 |
| 7 | 2 | 3 | IndustryID | InduNam111 |
| 8 | 2 | 3 | IndustryID | InduNam112 |
| 9 | 2 | 3 | IndustryID | InduNam121 |
| 10 | 2 | 3 | IndustryID | InduNam211 |
| 11 | 2 | 3 | IndustryID | InduNam311 |

Is it okay to have multiple empty parentId's?
Is this transformation ok?

Comment: I can count: 1 section, 1 division, 1 group, 4 classes. That is, a total of seven elements. Your new model should have 7 entries, but I only see 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the parent for the root node as null is fine - though in some designs this is populated with the same value as the record itself rather than having to deal with nulls e.g.

| ID | ParentID | Level | Type | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SecNam1 | 1 | SectorID1 | SecNam1 |

Also, having different versions of the same value in the TYPE column looks odd. I would have expected just "SectorID" not "SectorID1", "SectorID2", "SectorID3". The difference between different sectors is handled by the name of the sector e.g. like you have done with "Division".

Did you mean the level of "SectorID3" to be 2 rather than 1 - or is that just a typo?

Comment: Thank you!
With the "SectorID1", "SectorID2" and "SectorID3" i wanted to illustrate that there are different Sectors e.g. Energy, Technology etc.. and each sector would have his own ID.

Oh, yes. it is just a typo.. SectorID3 should have the level 1

Comment: But wouldn't the type always just be "Sector" and the names would be "Energy", "Technology", etc.?

Comment: Yes, it would be...